# Pandas interpolation 'spline' method not working

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, interpolation

I am trying to run the following code on a 200,000 row dataset to interpolate whilst grouping values:

```
g = df['Value'].mask(df['Value'].notnull(),df['Value'].isnull().cumsum()).ffill()

df['Value'] = (df.groupby(['Group', g])['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method="spline", order=1)))
```

When I run it I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/base_data.py", line 151, in <module>
    df['Value'] = (df.groupby(['Group', g])['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method="spline", order=1)))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 226, in apply
    return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 859, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 892, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 213, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "C:/Users/xxx/base_data.py", line 151, in <lambda>
    df['Value'] = (df.groupby(['Group', g])['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method="spline", order=1)))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6879, in interpolate
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 561, in interpolate
    return self.apply("interpolate", **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 406, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1140, in interpolate
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1233, in _interpolate
    interp_values = np.apply_along_axis(func, axis, data)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in apply_along_axis
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 379, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1229, in func
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\missing.py", line 303, in interpolate_1d
    **kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\missing.py", line 364, in _interpolate_scipy_wrapper
    terp = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=order, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack2.py", line 177, in __init__
    xe=bbox[1], s=s)
dfitpack.error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=1
```

I'm not sure if it's because I don't have a certain package installed, but that's my best guess.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The error message is not about a missing package. You need at least `k+1` (where `k` is the degree of the spline) data points to compute the interpolation for every group. You should check the size of every group and take a look at [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny in some of the groups I have only one value - do you know how I can still use spline without erroring on these groups?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny something like this sudo code:
if group size = 1 then 'linear'
else 'spline' ?